# jQuery - Possible copy row table using method select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to try something new,

Is this possible if we select row table, then copy it by selecting element?

*.ex* : When I select row table and want to copy it, copy it using method 'Click selected folder'.

> It's like we use function:
>
> *If user select ID `#folder1`, copy row to ID `#table1`*
>
> *If user select ID `#folder2`, copy row to ID `#table2`*

**My previous code for copy row and i want to change it :**

*because this just copy by searching for table*

<kbd>**Try This JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```
$('#Copy').on('click', function() {
    var tables = $(".allTable").find("table*[id]").not("#table1");
    tables.each(function() {
      console.log(this.id);
      var tbl_id = this.id;
      var $elem = $(this)
      var r = confirm("Copy to table " + tbl_id + "?");
      var table_to_copy = $elem.dataTable();
      if (r == true) {
        copyRows(mainTable, table_to_copy);
        alert("Copied!");
      } else {
        // do nothing..
      }
    });
  });
}); // end of  $(document).ready...

function copyRows(fromTable, toTable) {
  var $row = fromTable.find(".selected");
  $.each($row, function(k, v) {
    if (this !== null) {
      addRow = fromTable.fnGetData(this);
      toTable.fnAddData(addRow);
    }
  });
}
```

The example what i want if we seen JSFiddle,

*Remove the 'Copy Row' button and just 'Copy by clicking Table name [Table 2, Table 3]' .*

> I'm need reference for create this function.

**I hope you understand, any help would be greatly appreciated**

Comment: Please include your "*[mcve]*" code (the relevant HTML, CSS and JavaScript) in your question, don't just link to an external demo hosted elsewhere and expect us to go look.

Comment: just posted an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you want the selected rows to be copied to the respective table when we click on header `<h>` with label `TABLE2` OR `TABLE3` rather than clicking on the button. See below if this is how you want it to work ?

```js
// Code goes here
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*********** mainTable ***************/
  var mainTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
    "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/zvujb",
    "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },
      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],
    "scrollY": "200px",

  }); // mainTable 

  /*********** SecondTable ***************/
  var secondTable = $('#table2').dataTable({

    "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },

      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],

    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": "true"

  }); // secondTable

  /*********** ThirdTable ***************/
  var ThirdTable = $('#table3').dataTable({

    "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },

      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],

    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": "true"

  }); // ThirdTable

  /*************** SelecT OPTION ****************/

  mainTable.on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

  $('#copyToTable2,#copyToTable3').on('click', function() {

    let $elem = $(this);
    var table = $("#table" + $elem.attr('id').replace(/[a-zA-Z]/ig, ''));
    var tbl_id = table.attr('id');

    var $row = mainTable.find(".selected");
    if (!$row.length) {
      console.log('You must select some rows to copy first');
      return;
    } else {
      var r = confirm("Copy to table " + tbl_id + "?");
      var table_to_copy = table.dataTable();
      if (r == true) {
        copyRows(mainTable, table_to_copy);
        console.log("Copied!");
        setTimeout('console.clear()', 2000);
      } else {
        // do nothing..
      }

    }

  });
}); // end of  $(document).ready...

function copyRows(fromTable, toTable) {
  var $row = fromTable.find(".selected");

  $.each($row, function(k, v) {
    if (this !== null) {
      addRow = fromTable.fnGetData(this);
      toTable.fnAddData(addRow);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

#table2_wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#table1_wrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
  background-color: #b0bed9;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #a6b3cd;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd:hover.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even:hover.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.odd:hover.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr.even:hover.selected>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #a1aec7;
}

#Copy {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="allTable">
  <div>
    <h2>TABLE 1</h2>
    <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Audience Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <h2 id="copyToTable2">TABLE 2</h2>
    <table id="table2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Audience Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
  <h2 id="copyToTable3">TABLE 3</h2>
  <div>
    <table id="table3" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Audience Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is really pretty .. I am very grateful, Thanks Muhammad.

Comment: :) glad it helped you out @CalvinAnanda

Answer (score 1):

So what you do so far is running your "find table" function each time someone clicks the copy button.

```
var tables = $(".allTable").find("table*[id]").not("#table1");
// ...
var tbl_id = this.id; //this is one of the tables of the upper set
var r = confirm("Copy to table " + tbl_id + "?");
```

This logic finds all tables of yours already. So isntead of searching all the tables each time the user clicks on the copy button you can create a new button for each element in `tables` set instead at the start of the page load. Each button can then have an copy logic that is executed in the context of the specific table.

```
$.ready(function(){
    var tables = $(".allTable").find("table*[id]").not("#table1");
    tables.each(function(){
        var currentTable = $(this),
            tbl_id = currentTable.attr('id'),
            newButton = $('<button type="button">Copy to table ' + tbl_id + '</button>');
        $('#Copy').parent().append(newButton);
        newButton.click(function(){
            var r = confirm("Copy to table " + tbl_id + "?");
            //Copy the rows to the currentTable variable
        });
    });
});
```

Should be a good start to develop a solution.

Also since you will want to delete the generic `#copy` button you ned to find another logic to get the wrapper for the copy buttons.

Comment: ahh sorry i'm wrong if i'm delete copy row. but, do you forgeting adding `var`  on `tbl_id = currentTable.getAttr('id'),` ?

Comment: I am not using a semicolon at the end of the declaration row, so i can declare the next variables without using `var` again.

Comment: Again I was wrong, I just learned javascript and I just remembered it, thanks.

Comment: i got this error : `Uncaught TypeError: currentTable.getAttr is not a function`

Comment: Yeah sorry, the method is named `attr()`, not `getAttr()`. Fixed it